# WordPress drop down menu horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: css, wordpress

Creating a menu in WordPress. Instead of making the drop down menu to be vertical, I want the drop down menu to be horizontal.

See [this](https://www.bluerunnersolutions.com/) website for an example. Hover over *OUR SECTORS* to see the menu. The menu I want doesn't have to be full width on the screen.

Couldn't find any solutions for this yet. Only found solutions for multiple menu columns, like done with the [Max Mega Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/). I **don't** want to have multiple columns, but just a horizontal menu.

Is there any CSS or plugin available for this?

**Edit:** Website of the theme with the same menu [here](http://demos.themetrust.com/create/)

Comment: then use float:left; for the li tag and remove display:block

Answer (score 0):

I would give the `<ul>` a style of `display: flex`. Then you can move around the flex items with `justify-content`.
You can read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information about flexbox.

Sorry, it is really hard to help you without any examples.

Comment: I can share the demo site from the theme. It is the same menu. Note that the dropdown under Portfolio is 2 columns. This is not what I want, it should only be horizontal instead of vertical. http://demos.themetrust.com/create/

Comment: Then you can just do what I said. Tried it a second ago, you don't even need to add any more styles than the `display: flex` on the `<ul>` element

Comment: I probably did something wrong the first time, it's working now! Cheers. Do you maybe also know how I can add a second row if there are more than, let's say, 4 elements?

Comment: If the number of items in one row can be dynamic, you can just add `flex-wrap: wrap` and a `max-width` to the ul. I really recommend the article I posted, it's a good read if you want to learn more about flexbox :)